# Sql Job multiple query in 1 step

Tags: sql-server

This is an example of data that will be in column1

```
Column1
Test1
test2
test3
```

I then run this query

```
Declare @Id uniqueidentifier
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
SELECT Id 
FROM DB1.table 
WHERE Column1 is not null
OPEN db_cursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @id   

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   
    update DB1.table 
    set Column1 = (select top(1) Column2 from DB2.table order by newid())
    where Id = @id

   FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @id   
END   

CLOSE db_cursor   
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

This is the output I get

```
Column1
tom
jack
bob
```

I created this code which replaces a column from a DB1 table with DB2 table column data. This works fine when I run it as a job on the sql server agent.

I want to run the same query to change more databases with the same column. So the FROM query I want to add more Databases like From DB1.table, DB2.table, DB3.table...

It doesn't work without the cursor because It duplicates the values after the update like this.

```
column1
tom
tom
tom
```

Comment: In the first place you should never, ever do an update in a cursor. Use a set based operation. Read: http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Cursors_and_How_to_Avoid_Them

Comment: is db1.table in an another db than db2.table or does it have the namespace db1 and the other has the namespace db2 ?

Comment: They are different databases

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 0):

1Do you want to minimise the amount of text you write you can do it like this

```
update DB1.table set Column1 = (select top(1) Column2 from DB2.table order by newid()) where Column1 is not null
update DB2.table set Column1 = (select top(1) Column2 from DB2.table order by newid()) where Column1 is not null
update DB3.table set Column1 = (select top(1) Column2 from DB2.table order by newid()) where Column1 is not null
```

Using cursor is usually not the best thing to do.

Sorry about the bug. It is correct that this will only result in the same row for all the updates.

```
    update  DB1..[Table] set Column1 =randomizedCol
    from DB1..[Table] inner join 
    (
        select id,randomizedCol from 
            (select id, row_number() over (order by id) as col1RowNr from  DB1..[Table] ) as level41 inner join 
            (select column2 as randomizedCol,row_number() over (order by newId()) as col2RowNr from  DB2..[Table]) as level42
        on col1rowNr = col2RowNr
    ) as randomizedOutput
    on randomizedOutput.id =  DB1..[Table].id
```

This will get you what you want and is much faster. and then you copy this 3 times :( for each database you want to do this for.. You can put this into a string and use exec(@sqlString) if you have many databases.

Comment: The problem with this is that It will not loop through all the rows from DB2 table so it will pass 1 name and duplicate it in every database.

Comment: I tested it and it duplicates one name into all the databases. Any other solution?

Comment: Yes I have updated my answer. This should get you what you want but it is a bit long again like your orginal question but it does not rely on cursor

Comment: From What I followed here It seems like you are setting column2 which is the column from the database I am copying from. I need to update database1's column.

Comment: OH sorry it is right but when I test it I get this error 

Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Invalid column name 'Column2'.

Comment: OH sorry again It works perfect but It still duplicates the full column with the same value

Comment: Of course set col2=randomziedCol should be column1=randomizedCol in your db. Ive updated the answer. And I have checked it in my database and it randomizes the db1.table value. Are you sure it does not work?

Comment: Any Idea? It's only duplicating

Comment: That's What I did and it executed but it's duplicating everything so it's same as `update DB1.table set Column1 = (select top(1) Column2 from DB2.table order by newid()) where Column1 is not null`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36023/discussion-between-archlight-and-mohammed-tahir)

Answer (score -1):

Stop using a cursor and write three set-based update statements. It will be less code and run faster too.

Comment: I tested it and it duplicates one name into all the databases when I use the code:
`update DB1.table set Column1 = (select top(1) Column2 from   DB2.table order by newid()) where Column1 is not null`

`update DB2.table set Column1 = (select top(1) Column2 from DB2.table order by newid()) where Column1 is not null`

`update DB3.table set Column1 = (select top(1) Column2 from DB2.table order by newid()) where Column1 is not null`      
 Any other solution?

Comment: Perhaps you shoule show us some sample dat in the table and expected results.